# php archive are be called more than once

Tags: jquery, html, post

well, i have this jquery post:

```
$('.form-submit').click(function(){

    var form = $(this).attr('data-form');

    $("#"+form).submit(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "../assets/action/action.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data)
            {   
                $(".return-post-msg").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
})
```

the thing is, its working fine, but if i click the button.form-submit again, the jquery are called once normally BUT the action.php file are called twice, and if i click again, 3x... if clcik againx..  all i have in my action.php is

```
echo "<script> alert('".$method." aaaaa'); </script>";
```

for check how many times the file is being called...

Here is the HTML:

```
            <form id="create_requisite">

                <input type="hidden" name="method" value="create_requisite" />

                <div class="modal-heading"> <!-- Start of modal-heading -->

                    <h3>Create Requisite</h3>

                </div> <!-- End of modal-heading -->

                <div class="modal-body"> <!-- Start of modal-body -->

                    <div class="form-group"> <!-- Start of form-group -->

                        <label>Requisite Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-primary" name="name_requisite" />

                    </div> <!-- End of form-group -->

                </div> <!-- End of modal-body -->

                <div class="modal-footer"> <!-- Start of modal-footer -->

                    <span class="return-post-msg"></span>
                    <button class="btn btn-default form-submit" data-form="create_requisite">Create</button>

                </div> <!-- End of modal-footer -->

            </form>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: So you want to disable the button when it is clicked? Or do you want to check server-side if the form is submitted multiple times?

Comment: i want to click whatever i want, but ever time i click, i want to call only once the action.php

Comment: Can you share the relevant HTML part, please ? Is there multiple forms ?

Comment: i'm new in stackoverflow.. could'n paste the code ahhaa, check the image please https://ibb.co/cz7Crk

Comment: Just edit your question to add the code.

Comment: So, only one form, isn't it ?

Comment: @FelipeIwamoto Why couldn't you paste your code? An image of code is pretty useless.

Comment: thanks hehe, i made it

Answer (score 1):

You're listening to both a click event and a submit event which is probably causing the event to fire multiple times. Instead, just listen for the submit event.

```
$(this).attr('data-form').on('submit', function(e) {
  // make your ajax call
});
```

You can also use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) while declaring your event handler so that it will only ever handle the event once.

```
$(this).attr('data-form').one('submit', function(e) {
  // make your ajax call
});
```

However, use this carefully otherwise users may need to refresh the page just so they can fix something on the form after they try to submit.